# Duplicate keys in a json file

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

When calling `update_data()`, it's meant to pass if there is the user.id in the .json file. All it does is add the same id to the .json file. So basically the .json file has 2 same keys as user.id.
I am assuming its something to do with the `update_data()` function but I can be wrong.

```
class LevelingSystem(commands.Cog):
    """ Leveling system for discord """

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):


        async def update_data(levels, user):
            if user not in levels:
                levels[user] = {}
                levels[user]["experience"] = 0
                levels[user]["level"] = 1
                print(" Registered {} to .json; set default;".format(user))


        async def add_experience(levels, user):

            experience_user = levels[user]["experience"]   # gets the current user exp
            exp = random.randint(1, 5)    # random exp
            experience_user += exp   # adds the generated exp to the current exp
            levels[user]["experience"] = experience_user    #sets the user exp to that number

        async def on_level_up(levels, user, message):

            current_level = levels[user]["level"]
            exp_next_level = 4 * (current_level + 1 ** 2)
            exp = levels[user]["experience"]
            if exp > exp_next_level:
                old_level = levels[user]["level"]
                new_level = old_level + 1
                levels[user]["experience"] = 0
                print(" {} advanced to lvl {}".format(user, new_level))
                await message.channel.send(":partying_face: {} you have reached level {}".format(user.mention, new_level))


        if message.author.bot:
            return
        else:
            with open("X:\\Code\\Projects\\Python\\AlphaWolf\\cogs\\levels.json", 'r') as f:
                levels = json.loads(f)

            await update_data(levels, message.author.id)
            await add_experience(levels, message.author.id)
            await on_level_up(levels, message.author.id, message)

            with open("X:\\Code\\Projects\\Python\\AlphaWolf\\cogs\\levels.json",  'w') as f:
                json.dump(levels, f)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(LevelingSystem(bot))
```

Comment: Consider using a database (e.g. sqlite) here. JSON is not a good fit for this kind of work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `json` library in a discord cog, here is a simple way to do it :

```py
class LevelingSystem(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.base_xp = 200
        self.factor = 2

    @staticmethod
    def get_data():
        with open('members.json', 'r') as file:
            return loads(file.read())

    @staticmethod
    def set_data(members):
        with open('members.json', 'w') as file:
            file.write(dumps(members, indent=2))

   @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        members = self.get_data()
        members.append({'name': member.name, 'id': member.id, 'level': 0,'xp': 0})
        self.set_data(members)
    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_remove(self, member):
        members = self.get_data()
        members.remove({'name': member.name, 'id': member.id, 'level': member.level,'xp': member.xp})
        self.set_data(members)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        author = message.author.id
        members = self.get_data()
        for member in members:
            if author == member['id']:
                member['xp'] += randint(5, 10)
            if member['xp'] > self.base_xp * (member['level']+1 * self.factor):
                member['level'] += 1
                await message.channel.send(f":partying_face: {message.author.mention} you have reached level {member['level'] !}")
        self.set_data(members)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(LevelingSystem(bot))
```

This is a good solution if you have few users tho. On a big server, you would have to create a database, you would have better performances.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll let you now if this worked when im home.